# RLMObjects not recognised as the same in Realm Cocoa

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a tableView containing RLMObjects and want to search for the row containing a specific RLMObject.
After casting the RLMResult object to its original type it is not the same as its original object:

```
    // ... adding a todoA with !isCompleted to defaultRealm()
    var firstItem = Todo.objectsWhere("isCompleted == false")[0] as! ToDo
    if firstItem == todoA {
         // todoA is != firstItem even-though they should be the same object
    }
```

How can I compare two RLMObjects without having to implement the primaryKey allocation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RLMObject` does not conform to Swift's `Equatable` protocol, allowing `==` and `!=` comparisons. Depending on the equality semantics you want for your objects, you can use the following extension on `RLMObject`:

```
extension RLMObject: Equatable {}
func == <T: RLMObject>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool {
  return lhs.isEqualToObject(rhs)
}
```

Comment: `isEqualToObject` still does not give the correct result. Can I somehow access the computed (internal) primaryKey and compare those?

Comment: isEqualToObject will use these equality semantics: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/8a49cab247de5005e328cf486fe85fbf13d3f1cf/Realm/RLMObjectBase.mm#L279-L303. If you want different semantics, you're free to do so.

Comment: `(o1 == o2)` does not to give `true` even if it is the same object. Seems like getting `o1` as a RLMResult and casting it makes its identity different from its original. Is there any way I can the primaryKey without implementing it myself? Don't want to manage the unique keys for the object myself, getting them would enable a comparison though.

Comment: The equality semantics are defined in the link I just shared. If you need different semantics, you'll need to build that yourself.

Comment: Okay, thanks. seams odd to me that Realm can not figure out if two objects are referencing the same object in the database.

Comment: Realm can of course determine if two accessor objects point to the same underlying data. Please see the equality semantic logic in Realm's source here: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/0ff7c2627f054ba19e204d0d3e03b4296f365b67/Realm/RLMObjectBase.mm#L283-L307. If you've found a scenario in which those semantics aren't being applied to determine if two objects are equal, that is a bug and you're encouraged to file a GitHub issue.

Comment: Could you please tell my how I can compare two `RLMObject`s using this `RLMObjectBaseAreEqual`? The above code does not result in `true` for the same object, where one is casted from `RLMResult`.

Comment: If you use isEqualToObject, you're using RLMObjectBaseAreEqual